# Simple PHP Condition help: if($Var1 = in list($List) and $Cond2) - Is this posslbe?

Tags: php, list, conditional-statements

Is this a possible function?

I need to check if a variable is existent in a list of ones I need to check against and also that cond2 is true
eg

```
if($row['name'] == ("1" || "2" || "3") && $Cond2){
    doThis();
}
```

It's not working for me and all I changed in the copy paste was my list and the variable names

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
if(in_array($row['name'], array('1', '2', '3')) && $Cond2) {
  doThis();
}
```

PHP's `in_array()` docs: http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

Comment: Just as a minor side note, depending on how big your "exceptions-array" is you might wanna put $Cond2 as the first element of the boolean expression (assuming it is already atomic and not some sort of potentially expensive function call).

Answer (score 3):

You're lookin for the function [`in_array()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php).

```
if (in_array($row['name'], array(1, 2, 3)) && $cond2) {
    #...
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if (in_array($name , array( 'Alice' , 'Bob' , 'Charlie')) && $condition2 ) {
 /* */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use in_array function 
if(in_array($row['name'], array(1,2,3)) && $cond2){
do ...
}

Answer (score 0):

```
$name = $row['name'];
if (($name == "1" || $name == "2" || $name == "3") && $cond2)
{
  doThis();
}
```

Comment: that's a possibility but the others are smarter

Comment: I agree, in_array is a better way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I have something simpler than that, if it's still possible...

```
if(strpos("1,2,3", $row['name']) !== false) && $Cond2) {
  doThis();
}
```